# ggplot2 change colours how

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to do a ggplot2 scatter plot

```
    scores <- data.frame( SampleID = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 5), PC1 = rnorm(15), PC2 = rnorm(15) )
library( ggplot2 )
ggplot( scores, aes( x = PC1, y = PC2, colour = SampleID ) ) +
  geom_point()
```

this code colours the data points in a gradient, so that thez are often not really distinguishable. I saw that

```
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_point.html
```

uses

```
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
```

for colouring but if I enter

```
ggplot( scores, aes( x = PC1, y = PC2, colour = SampleID ) ) +
      geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
```

I get an error message

```
 in factor(cyl) : object 'cyl' not found
```

can somebody tell me how I can colour the scatter graph with either not gradient colours OR different symbols?

Comment: The error says it all. `cyl` does not exist. Use your variable names (`SampleID`).

Answer (score 6):

`scale_color_manual` let's you pick the colors used.

```
ggplot( scores, aes( x = PC1, y = PC2, colour = SampleID ) ) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "dodgerblue2"))
```

The `cyl` in the example refers to the `cyl` column of the `mtcars` dataset used in the example. If you would rather use shapes then colors, don't use the `colour` aesthetic, use the `shape` aesthetic instead.

```
ggplot( scores, aes( x = PC1, y = PC2, shape = SampleID ) ) +
    geom_point()
```

If you want to choose shapes (using usual R `pch` codes), then use `scale_shape_manual`.