# How to specify the colour of specific data points?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have a small set of data where I want to give each point a different colour (Border and Fill), which I have specified within the data as extra columns. I've tried to classify these as colours rather than text using

```
colour = data[,5]
```

and

```
colour <- as.character(data[,5])
```

but neither seems to work. R keeps just assigning random colours, ie. all the reds are the same colour, but not red! My plot looks like:

```
qplot(x, y, data, pch=21, col=Border, bg=Fill)
```

Not sure what else to do.

Comment: ggplot likes to work with column names, not indices. So whatever the name is of your 5th column, say `"color_column"`, do `color = color_column`.

Comment: Also, ggplot is different from base graphics, so base graphics options like `col` and `bg` won't work. The ggplot argument for the fill color is (nicely intuitive) `fill`, so you can do `fill = fill_column`. In that case, you'll also want to pick a shape that takes a fill, try `shape = 22`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For future reference, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). You are much more likely to get help if your questions conform to these guidelines.

Comment: @Gregor So my pch, col, fill commands are now working nicely but I still can't get it to register the correct colours.

I've tried `colour = data["Fill"]`, where "Fill" is the name of the column but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Just do `colour = Fill`, where `Fill` is the unquoted name of the column. You're already passing your data in, you don't need to re-specify it.

Comment: If you share a small, reproducible data set, something like `dput(droplevels(head(data, 10)))`, I could actually show you code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing sample data from you, let's use the `diamonds` data set built-in to `ggplot2`.

```
# really, let's use a subset
di = head(diamonds, 500)
```

I'd strongly recommend using `ggplot` rather than `qplot`:

```
ggplot(di, aes(x = carat, y = price, color = cut, fill = clarity)) +   
    geom_point(shape = 21)
```

Inside `aes()` you use **unquoted** column names. For something that is a constant, it goes *outside* the `aes()` aesthetic mappings, in this case `shape = 21`. (You can also use `pch = 21` if you prefer the base graphics style name).

`qplot` is intended to be a shortcut, and it should work something like this:

```
qplot(data = di, x = carat, y = price, col = cut, fill = clarity, pch = 21)
```

but in this case it can't tell what's in your data (all the unquoted column names) and what's not (`21`), and since `21` is a numeric it assumes there will be a continuous scale for shapes, which isn't allowed. So there's an error.

A simpler plot would do fine with `qplot`

```
qplot(data = di, x = carat, y = price, col = cut)
```

but for this more complicated case, you're better off with `ggplot` as above.

Comment: OK, so I have a table of data like this:

          `Team ShotsPG Possession PassSuccess   Fill Border`

`1       Manchester City    20.6       56.9        85.7   blue  white`

`2                    Arsenal    20.0       56.5        85.6    red  white`

So I want each team to have a uniquely coloured point.

Using the code you have given, I still have the same problem - it is not reading my "Fill" column as a list of colours.

Comment: Right, that's not how ggplot works. You should have a column that's a factor where you want a different fill for each level. It will pick fill colors by default and give you a nice legend. If you want to specify colors, use `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: If you update your question with reproducibly shared data, like with `dput(droplevels(head(data, 10)))` I can maybe show more explicitly. Most any introduction to ggplot will cover this.

Comment: Or you could see similar questions on SO, like [Pick color of choice... using ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24230094/903061), or [ggplot2 change colours how](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16308901/903061), which is actually my answer from a couple years ago.